# Is there a way to create a function pointer to a method in Rust?

Tags: rust

For example,

```
struct Foo;

impl Foo {
    fn bar(&self) {}
    fn baz(&self) {}
}

fn main() {
    let foo = Foo;
    let callback = foo.bar;
}
```

```
error[E0615]: attempted to take value of method `bar` on type `Foo`
  --> src/main.rs:10:24
   |
10 |     let callback = foo.bar;
   |                        ^^^ help: use parentheses to call the method: `bar()`
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

With [fully-qualified syntax](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html#fully-qualified-syntax-for-disambiguation-calling-methods-with-the-same-name), `Foo::bar` will work, yielding a `fn(&Foo) -> ()` (similar to Python).

```
let callback = Foo::bar;
// called like
callback(&foo);
```

However, if you want it with the `self` variable already bound (as in, calling `callback()` will be the same as calling `bar` on the `foo` object), then you need to use an explicit closure:

```
let callback = || foo.bar();
// called like
callback();
```