# Pass an mutable instance method to a function

Tags: rust

I am teaching myself Rust by creating a toy SDL2 lib for myself.

I created something similar in Go and am trying to port my code across. So far, this is the problem I cannot overcome. I want my library to have callback to a function on the program state so I can have keyboard events sent from my library code to my client code.

The aim is for the keydown events from the SDL keyboard event pump should trigger the on_keydown function on the state object. If I remove the State struct and just use static functions then it works. Of course this prevents me from changing the state of the program based on keyboard actions.

I am trying to use external crates as little as possible.

The relevant parts of the library.

```
pub enum GameCommand {
    Quit,
    Continue,
}

pub struct Window {
    keydown_event: fn(Event) -> GameCommand,
}

impl Window {
    pub fn set_keydown_event(&mut self, f: fn(e: Event) -> GameCommand) {
        self.keydown_event = f;
    }

    pub fn run(&mut self) -> Result<(), String> {
        let mut event_pump = self.game.context.event_pump()?;

        'running: loop {
            // Handle events
            for event in event_pump.poll_iter() {
                let mut gc = GameCommand::Continue;
                match event {
                    Event::Quit { .. } => break 'running,
                    Event::KeyDown { repeat: false, .. } => {
                        gc = (self.keydown_event)(event);
                    }
                    _ => {}
                }
                if let GameCommand::Quit = gc  {
                    break 'running
                }
            }
        }
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

Now the relevant part of the client bin.

```
struct State {
    bgcolor: Color,
}

impl State {
    fn on_keydown(&mut self, event: Event) -> GameCommand {
        
        match event {
            Event::KeyDown { keycode: Some(Keycode::R), .. } => {
                self.bgcolor.r += 1;
                GameCommand::Continue
            },
            Event::KeyDown { keycode: Some(Keycode::G), .. } => {
                self.bgcolor.g += 1;
                GameCommand::Continue
            },
            Event::KeyDown { keycode: Some(Keycode::B), .. } => {
                self.bgcolor.b += 1;
                GameCommand::Continue
            },
            Event::KeyDown { keycode: Some(Keycode::Escape), ..} => {
                GameCommand::Quit
            },
            _ => GameCommand::Continue,
        }
    }
}
```

Now the main function.

```
fn main()  -> Result<(), String> {
    let mut state = State {
        bgcolor: Color::RGB(0, 0, 0),
    };

    let mut window = Window::new();
    window.set_keydown_event(state.on_keydown);

    Ok(())
}
```

There is a far bit of code skipped to keep it shortish. The error I get with this code is.

```
{
    "code": "E0615",
    "message": "attempted to take value of method `on_keydown` on type `State`\n\nmethod, not a field\n\nhelp: use parentheses to call the method: `(_)`",
    
}
```

If I `window.set_keydown_event(state.on_keydown);` I get this error.

```
{
    "code": "E0308",
    "message": "mismatched types\n\nexpected fn pointer, found enum `sdlgame::GameCommand`\n\nnote: expected fn pointer `fn(sdl2::event::Event) -> sdlgame::GameCommand`\n               found enum `sdlgame::GameCommand`",
}
```

I assume the problem is the difference in function signatures. In the set_keydown_event function it expects.

`fn(Event) -> GameCommand`

Which is why a plain function not associated with a struct works. For the instance method to mutate state it requires the signature.

`fn on_keydown(&mut self, event: Event) -> GameCommand`

Initially, I am trying to achieve this is a single threaded manner as I am trying to keep things simple for me to reason out. Multi-threading will come later.

Is this possible in Rust and what is the correct way of achieving this result?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So I've looked about and it would seem the observer pattern isn't really a good fit for Rust. Too many problems with the borrow checker. So I am going down the ECS route with Specs.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you need to use [function traits](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.FnMut.html) as well as an explicit closure so the call is bound to the variable. So, you'd change your `Window` to use a function trait:

```rust
// F is now the function type
pub struct Window<F: FnMut(Event) -> GameCommand> {
    keydown_event: F,
}
```

Then you'd change your impl to support that function trait:

```rust
// put generic in impl
impl<F: FnMut(Event) -> GameCommand> Window<F> {
    // take F as the parameter type now
    pub fn set_keydown_event(&mut self, f: F) {
        self.keydown_event = f;
    }

    pub fn run(&mut self) -> Result<(), String> {
        // this function should stay the same
    }
}
```

Then, you'd pass an [explicit closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24728394/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-function-pointer-to-a-method-in-rust) to it:

```rust
fn main() -> Result<(), String> {
    let mut state = State {
        bgcolor: Color::RGB(0, 0, 0),
    };

    let mut window = Window::new();
    // binds the on_keydown function to the state variable
    window.set_keydown_event(|x| state.on_keydown(x));

    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. IT hasn't quite worked though. I have a constructor for the Window struct. which throws up this error.

src\lib.rs:30:17
30 -> Result<Window, Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
   |