# Extracting raw pointer to a trait function

Tags: rust

Trying to comprehend how Rust's vtables work but failing...

```rust
struct Struct {
    data: u32
}

impl Struct {
    fn my_data(&self) -> u32 { self.data }
}

trait Trait {
    fn get_data(&self) -> u32;
}

impl Trait for Struct {
    fn get_data(&self) -> u32 { self.my_data() }
}

fn what_data(a: &dyn Trait) -> u32 {
    // let ptr = &a.get_data as *const _; // I actually need to get a raw pointer to a.get_data here
    a.get_data()
}

fn main() {
    let a = Struct { data: 42 };
    println!("{}", what_data(&a));
}
```

How to get a raw pointer to the function entry point given a `&dyn Trait` pointer to a trait that declares the function?

Comment: This is a really hard question. I don't think there's an easy way to get this pointer :/ is there any way that your problem would be solvable without this? I think resolving the vtable is a compiler internal detail, I don't think it's exposed to the user, at least not yet :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rust's vtable structure is not accessible from Rust code.

If you just want to understand how this works, then we can use little unsafe magic (**but none of this is guaranteed!**):

```rust
fn what_data(a: &dyn Trait) -> u32 {
    unsafe {
        // `&dyn Trait` is stored as two references, the data pointer coming first and then the vtable
        // pointer. But again, this is not guaranteed!
        // On nightly we can extract the metadata with `std::ptr::metadata()`, but unfortunately it doesn't
        // give access to the full vtable, only to an opaque struct representing it :(
        let raw_dyn = std::mem::transmute::<&dyn Trait, [*const (); 2]>(a);
        // This is how the vtable is structured in memory (again, *currently*. Nothing is guaranteed!):
        #[repr(C)]
        struct Vtable {
            // First, comes the function to execute the drop glue. This is necessary for e.g. `Box<dyn Trait>`
            // to be able to drop the data correctly.
            _drop_in_place: fn(*mut ()),
            // Then, the struct size (`std::mem::size_of_val(&data)`). This is necessary for e.g. `Box<dyn Trait>`
            // to be able to correctly *deallocate* the data.
            _size: usize,
            // Then the alignment (`std::mem::align_of_val(&data)`) for the same purpose as the size.
            _align: usize,
            // And here, if you enable the unstable trait upcasting feature, comes the pointers to the supertraits'
            // vtables, so you can upcast. But we don't have supertraits, so this is empty.
            // And finally, the pointers to the methods: first supertrait methods, then the methods of the trait itself.
            // We only have one method and no supertraits, so this is easy.
            get_data: fn(*const ()) -> u32,
        }
        ((*raw_dyn[1].cast::<Vtable>()).get_data)(raw_dyn[0])
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f6aad6dcb4a1c057a75e4cdd75725bee).

But if you actually want to write code for that in one of your project, then use a closure like @Finomnis and @prog-fh suggested.

Comment: Ahahah, living on the edge, I like that! I would never use this, but it's beautiful!

Comment: Ah, I see now. I actually need to pass control to that function from some JIT-compiled code. Seems like locking it in closure and passing a pointer to that closure (although it would involve some lifetimes hell) would be better than relying on non-guaranteed structures. I just need to figure out what closure calling convention Rust uses (I really hope it is guaranteed :))

Comment: @s0me0ne The calling convention (called `"Rust"`) is indeed not guaranteed. If you need a guaranteed one, you need to use `extern "C"`, but closures don't support that, only functions. However, closures (capturing over variables) cannot be called from extern code anyway, as their layout is not guaranteed. You could make a function taking the `&dyn Trait` as a parameter, but its ABI is not specified so you cannot do that... I will add an answer with a possibility.

Comment: Accepting this answer as it answers the exact question asked. The other solutions are very helpful, too. It's always good to understand how things work, even if the final result is "you should never do it" :) Thanks to everyone participating!

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24728592/11527076) I would return a closure bound to the calling object.

```rust
struct Struct {
    data: u32,
}

impl Struct {
    fn my_data(&self) -> u32 {
        self.data
    }
}

trait Trait {
    fn get_data(&self) -> u32;
}

impl Trait for Struct {
    fn get_data(&self) -> u32 {
        self.my_data()
    }
}

fn what_data(a: &dyn Trait) -> impl Fn() -> u32 + '_ {
    // let ptr = &a.get_data as *const _; // I actually need to get a raw pointer to a.get_data here
    let p = || a.get_data();
    p
}

fn main() {
    let a = Struct { data: 42 };
    let p = what_data(&a);
    println!("~~> {}", p());
}
/*
~~> 42
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

When you need a stable vtable layout, it is common to *emulate* a vtable using custom struct. Here's how you can create a stable vtable, that you can pass to external code (even not written in Rust). I didn't put `drop_in_place`, `size` and `align` because this is only a borrowing vtable, if you need to put it in an owning pointer you need them too:

```rust
#[repr(C)]
pub struct StableVtable {
    get_data: unsafe extern "C" fn(*const ()) -> u32,
}

fn get_vtable_for<T: Trait>() -> &'static StableVtable {
    // Helper function to convert the ABI.
    unsafe extern "C" fn get_data<T: Trait>(this: *const ()) -> u32 {
        (*this.cast::<T>()).get_data()
    }

    // Use static promotion to create a `static` generic vtable.
    &StableVtable {
        get_data: get_data::<T>,
    }
}

#[repr(C)] // This struct is safe to pass to external code
#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
pub struct DynTraitRef<'a> {
    data: *const (),
    vtable: &'static StableVtable,
    _marker: std::marker::PhantomData<&'a ()>,
}

// This is not necessary for external code, but allows it to be used from Rust code.
impl Trait for DynTraitRef<'_> {
    fn get_data(&self) -> u32 {
        unsafe { (self.vtable.get_data)(self.data) }
    }
}

pub fn to_dyn_trait_ref<T: Trait>(v: &T) -> DynTraitRef<'_> {
    DynTraitRef {
        data: v as *const T as *const (),
        vtable: get_vtable_for::<T>(),
        _marker: std::marker::PhantomData,
    }
}

fn what_data(a: DynTraitRef<'_>) -> u32 {
    a.get_data()
}

fn main() {
    let a = Struct { data: 42 };
    println!("{}", what_data(to_dyn_trait_ref(&a)));
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=26c3823a3de56c2900c03844f516fac9).